# Cast interface list to implementation list or vice-versa

Tags: c#, oop, interface, windows-phone

I am just not getting how to convert or cast `List<ISomeImplementation>` to `List<SomeImplementation>`.

```
// lstOfImplemantation is of type `List<SomeImplementation>`
    List<ISomeImplementation> lstOfInterfaces = lstOfImplemantation; // how to convert it.
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do? this isn't going to be easy since there are different things that could implement this interface (see all cats are animals etc..) you could do `list.OfType<T>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because `A` derives from `B`, doesn't necessarily mean `X<A>` derives from `X<B>`.

In fact, `List<T>` is *invariant* in its generic type paramater `T`. This means `List<string>` isn't a subtype nor a supertype of `List<object>`, even though `string` derives from `object`.

Imagine if your list of interfaces contained instances of type `SomeOtherImplementation`. How would the cast work?

Instead, you should create a *new* list and cast each item in your list of interfaces to the concrete type.

```
List<SomeImplementation> lstOfImplementation =
             lstOfInterfaces.Cast<SomeImplementation>()
                            .ToList();
```

If you're not sure whether all instances are of type `SomeImplementation`, you can filter out those who aren't, using `OfType<T>`.

```
List<SomeImplementation> lstOfImplementation =
             lstOfInterfaces.OfType<SomeImplementation>()
                            .ToList();
```

Read also:

- [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee207183.aspx)
- [Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ in one way:

```
List<ISomeImplementation> lstOfInterfaces = lstOfImplemantation.Cast<IISomeImplementation>().ToList();
```

Casting interface to implementation is not good pratice. What if there some other implementations of that interface? You cannot assume that all implemtations are the of type `SomeImplementation`. If you are sure, use `List<SomeImplementation>`.